# MongoDB order documents based on multiple field expression

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of movies that include how many people have seen the movie depending on their age. An example would be:

```
{
   name : "Return of Jedi",
   kids : 5,
   adults : 10,
   seniors : 3
}
```

This would mean that "Return of the Jedi" was seen by 5 kids, 10 adults and 3 seniors.

I need to return a recommendation of movies based on their ranking. A ranking is calculated as the total of viewers for that movie that match the search. E.g. if I have a family of kids and adults, the rank for return of the Jedi would be 13 (#kids + #adults).

Can MongoDB sort by calculated expressions? How? If not, is there an alternative?

I thought of solving this using the Aggregation Framework by adding a computed field and then order by it. But wouldn't this be too resources consuming?

Comment: Which driver you are using?

Comment: java spring mongodb. mongodb is v2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use $project, then $add.

something like:

```
db.movies.aggregate({ $project: 
{ 
      movieName: "$name", 
      totalAudience: { $add : ["$kids","$adults","$seniors"]}
},
{ $sort : { totalAudience: -1 }}
);
```

would give you all movies ordered by total audience desc.

Comment: thanks. this is my initial direction. But I am curious if this is the most effective way. Is it heavy on performance? Is there a better way?

Comment: as long as you limit the aggregation early in the pipeline mongodb will make use of any indexes you have on the collection.  the sorted value will not be indexed (it's calculated) but by then you should have all the documents you're acting on.

Comment: an alternative way would be to hold an indexed, denormalised total value. but unless you're dealing with lots and lots of documents in the aggregation or speed is absolutely paramount, it's probably not worth it.